# Undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I am trying to return an integer value, but the function is returning undefined, even though the variables are declared and already have values. Could you help me by explaining why this happens in JS. I leave you the code.

````
var value = 0;
var max = 0;
var control = 0;

function solution(N) {
    let div = Math.trunc(N/2);
    let mod = N % 2;

    if (mod===1){
        if(max < value){
            max = value;
        }
        value = 0;
        control = 1;
    }else if(mod===0 && control === 1){
        value++;
    }
    
    if(div === 0){
        return max;
    }
    solution(div);
}

solution(1041)```
````

Comment: You are in SO Spanish you should post your question in [SOEnglish](https://stackoverflow.com/) and if you come from there then translate your question into our language so that it is better received and we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
if(div === 0){
    return max;
}
return solution(div);
```

Recuerda que necesitamos devolver algo en cada ejecución de la función recursiva.

Comment: Lo del voto negativo..... se puede saber porqué? El que de votos negativos debería de dar una explicación, así aprendemos todos.

Comment: No es mío, pero creo saber el motivo: suele pasar que cuando una pregunta muestra poco esfuerzo (por ejemplo, en este caso está en inglés, lo que demuestra poca atención por parte del OP), las respuestas se ven como una aceptación implícita de que la pregunta es suficientemente buena cuando realmente no lo es

Comment: @H.Díaz, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me funcionó.